# Multiple Groupings with a sum

Tags: sql

My Table :

```
ID | TIME OF CREATION | OWNER | STATE
1    2015-1-1           arpan   A  
2    2015-1-2           arpan   B
```

My desired o/p from my query is :

```
DATE | OWNER | COUNT(STATE = A) | COUNT(STATE = B) | ...
```

I checked out `SUM( CASE )` but you cant group by date and sum by owner right?

Stuck here. :(

Can someone help?

Comment: What did you try with the `sum(case)`? I think you should be able to make it work.

Comment: you can also group by date and owner

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select date, owner, sum(case when state = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as state_A,
       sum(case when state = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as state_b
from table t
group by date, owner;
```

Comment: Doesnt give me the desired output.

Comment: would Sum in conjuction with OVER ( Partition by ) work?

Comment: I understood the mistake ! there is no date field , rather a timestamp ( numeric ex. 1418112000000000 ) Want to finally show the date?
Can I user Convert( field, getdate() ) during the select?

Comment: Then use the appropriate database function for converting the timestamp to a datetime.  That functionality depends on the database, which you haven't specified.  Your question also is about a *date* not a *timestamp*.

Comment: Yes correct,  I wish to do it for a timestamp but group it for by the date in the timestamp. I edited my question.
Can I use this function within my Select Query itself? 
The database is actually Tenzing ( http://research.google.com/pubs/pub37200.html)